# Simple Revision Control for Eclipse and Android

Tags: android, svn

I'm a lone android developer using eclipse that's learning the ropes.  I have no plans on becoming a professional.

I'm looking for a simple solution to provide backups to my projects.  I've played around with UberSVN, Git, and tortoisehq but find it overkill.   Plus, I seemed to have a lot of issues with it (one minute working fine, next minute getting commit errors).

I just need a solution that if I mess something up in a project I can go back to an older version and fix.    Something with an easy to understand/use GUI interface and installer would be preferred.

Thanks,
Shannon

Comment: Just use tortoisesvn, and be done with it. Using strange and substandard tools will only bring you in trouble when they disappear in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SubClipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) pluging for Eclipse. One stop solution for your requirement. On the client side it integrates within the eclipse.

Comment: I'm using the SubClipse plugin with the UberSVN.  I just reinstalled UberSVN and everything seems fine now.  I think the probably was because I had multiple SVNs installed (to see which one I liked) and it was conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) is the easiest to use revision control client out there. It integrates seamlessly with with the windows shell. Just read the first chapter of the documentation and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you find UberSVN, Git, and tortoisehq overkill... try [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

Its easy and better for single user than other version control systems.

For integrating with eclipse use the plugin http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA

For complete tutorial on how to use TortoiseSVN in eclipse : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/

Comment: I actually really liked UberSVN but Eclipse keep giving me commit errors.  It would work for 4-5 commits and then stop working.  I had to disconnect from SVN, delete the resp and create the project over again.  Then it would let me commit changes again.  I wish I knew what was causing it because UberSVN is nice.

Comment: then TortoiseSVN is far better than nice.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) is the most common one. It integrates to right click menu. Once installed, create some test project, make 2 separate checkouts and try committing, causing conflicts, rolling back etc. That's how I learned.

There is a nice tutorial here:

http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html

Another great tool I recommend is [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) which integrates easily with TortoiseSVN. It's much better than the internal diff that comes with TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseHG isn't much harder TortoiseSVN really (in ordinary use-cases). TSVN is realy good choice, but, as subversion, have svn limitations and sharp corners in merges-handling (most important), which can have bad effect on f.e big refactoring stage

From other point of view, [Fossil SCM](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) have not nice GUI-frontend (CLI-only), but it is small portable (one exe) cross-platform application with **integrated** tickets and wiki *from a box*

Answer (score 0):

Try using eGit. Git is one of the best tools for version management and eGit for eclipse provides nice user interface for commit, push and pull.

Comment: eGit (Eclipse's Git) is definitely overkill for this user.  And when something weird happens (as it usually does with Git), it can be impossible to figure out solutions.  Check out this video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDeG4S-mJts) to understand just how difficult Git can be (and eGit is even *more* frustrating when it doesn't work!).

Comment: I don' think git can be any more difficult than svn.

Answer (score -3):

A really simple solution would be to open a Dropbox account and create your projects in the Dropbox folder. Dropbox keeps a history of all files so you can go back if you mess something up.

Comment: -1 This is a very "unrecommended" resolution. [See this link for reference](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/270978/771931/#msg_771931). There are certain files that are PC specific that should not be shared.